# Validating form in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a form with one input called 'name1', I 'd like to validate this input, making sure it has at least four characters. Here is my code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

   function validateForm()
   {
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name1"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
     alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
   }
```

```
     <form name="myForm" method="POST" action="write.jsp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
      Name: <input type="text" name="name1" value="<%=name%>" size="20"/>  <br> 
      <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="window.close()"/>
      </form>
```

This is not working, I think it's because this is a pop-up page and the alert from javascript couldn't pop-up again. Anyone could help me to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function validateForm()
{
   var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name1"].value;
   if (x.trim().length<=4) // check length of your name field
   {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the expression does help! But the alert is not popping up, is there any other way to display the error message?

Comment: Use `jquery` to show `error message` like, `$('#error-message').text('Please enter name');`

Answer (score 0):

widely accepted and reliable solution for such validation is to use

```
maxlength Attribute
```

no extra javascript validation is required..

e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="name1" value="<%=name%>" size="20" maxlength="4" />
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this, but how can the system indicate the message if the input is less than 4